# How to change the precision of the index of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a DateTimeIndex index. The DateTimeIndex has a minutes precision and I would like to turn it into days precision.
What I can do is:

```
df.index = df.index.values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What your asking for is called resampling: it's covered in [this section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling) in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply:

```
df.resample('D', how='first')
```